# display dataset label in Chart.js line

Tags: javascript

I am able to generate the line graph using Charts.js tool. There are two datasets, for the years 2014 and 2015. The tool tip displays only the monthly value, but not the dataset value. How to enable it? Neither `tooltipTemplate` not `multiTooltipTemplate` solves it. I need to display the years too. 
Here is the javascript code.

```
<script>
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "2015",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [3, 7, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 8, 0, 1, 0]
        },
        {
            label: "2014",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 5]
        }
    ]
};
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("myChart").width = window.innerWidth;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
    }
</script>
```

Here is the html code

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datasetLabel` in the tooltip template:

```
var options = {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %>"
}
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/caft9y2f/).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Is it possible to save the javascript class rather relying on external CDN? If so, the link to download please?

Comment: Sure, you can download the full bundle (sources, samples, docs) from [github](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/archive/v1.0.2.zip).
You can also save locally the [Chart.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js) file straight from the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

What version of chart.js are you using?

I can confirm that tooltips work using v1.0.1-beta2

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

but do not work using v0.2.0.

Version 1.0.1-beta2 is available from cdnjs.

Comment: sinto, I think it is 1.0.2. Even after using the CDN you suggested, I still don't see the label.

Comment: tried this?
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, {
    showTooltip: true,
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>"
});

Comment: Tried as you suggested, but no change. :(

Comment: can yo pls change the var data by 'chartData'

Comment: I did that or else I wouldn't have seen the line chart. I edited it to data at both places. I can see the chart but not the label. I even tried multiTooltipTemplate instead of tooltipTemplate